# Reducing code complexity to increase readability and get conditional logic working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to reduce code duplication in my controller which I have mocked up to test both on my browser and device. The core functionality works at the moment, but it currently violates the DRY principle. I attempted to add the following functionality which dictates what should be displayed on the home screen but it doesn't seem to be working at all:

1) empty-state - appears when $scope.facebookUserData and $scope.facebookUserPicture are null

2) showFacebookEmptyState - appears when $scope.facebookUserData and $scope.facebookUserPicture are not null but either one of $scope.userPicture , $scope.userProfile or $scope.userSelectedCategories are null

3) showDefaultState - appears when all $scope.userPicture , $scope.userProfile or $scope.userSelectedCategories are not null regardless of anything else

Does anyone have ideas on how to refactor the code below and make it easier to read? I am a bit overwhelmed by the mess it's become and I am struggling to find another approach.

**home.view.html**

```
<div class="empty-state" ng-show="showEmptyState">
  <img class="icon icon-home" src="img/user.svg">
  <div class="heading heading-padding">Set up your profile</div>
  <div class="subheading heading-padding">You will need to set up a profile before creating a resume. This will help us learn more about you
    <br><br>
    <button class="button button-balanced button-block remove-border-radius">Get Started</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="facebook-empty-state" ng-show="showFacebookEmptyState">
  <img class="icon icon-home img-circle" ng-src="{{ facebookUserPicture.data.base64_data }}">
  <div class="heading heading-padding">Welcome, {{ facebookUserData.first_name}}</div>
  <div class="subheading heading-padding">You will need to set up a profile before creating a resume. This will help us learn more about you.
    <br><br>
    <button class="button button-balanced button-block remove-border-radius" ui-sref="tab.setup-profile-facebook">Get Started</button>
</div>

<div class="default-state" ng-show="showDefaultState">
  You have signed up and are ready to go
</div>
```

**home.controller.js**

```
/*
*
*/
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('dingocv.controllers')
  .controller('HomeController', HomeController)


  function HomeController($scope, config, $cordovaNativeStorage, FacebookService, $ionicLoading, PhotoService, $log) {

    // On device
    if (window.cordova) {

      // Get Facebook access token
      $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("facebookAccessToken").then(function (value) {
        $scope.facebookAccessToken = value

        // Get Facebook user data
        FacebookService.getUserData($scope.facebookAccessToken).then(function(dataResponse) {
          $scope.facebookUserData = dataResponse.data;

          // Save Facebook user data
          $cordovaNativeStorage.setItem("facebookUserData", $scope.facebookUserData).then(function () {
          }, function(error) {
            console.error("Unable to cache user data: " + result);
            $ionicLoading.show({
              template: 'Unable to cache user data',
              duration: 1500
            })
          });
          $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = true;
          $scope.showEmptyState = false;
          $scope.showDefaultState = false;

          // Get Facebook user picture
          FacebookService.getUserPicture($scope.facebookUserData.id).then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.facebookUserPicture = dataResponse.data;
            PhotoService.getBase64FromImageURL($scope.facebookUserPicture.data.url, function(base64_data) {
              $scope.facebookUserPicture.data.base64_data = base64_data;

              // Save Facebook user picture
              $cordovaNativeStorage.setItem("facebookUserPicture", $scope.facebookUserPicture).then(function () {
              }, function(error) {
                console.error("Unable to cache user data: " + result);
                $ionicLoading.show({
                  template: 'Unable to cache user data',
                  duration: 1500
                })
              })
            });
          }, function(error) {
            $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = false;
            $scope.showEmptyState = true;
            $scope.showDefaultState = false;
            console.log(error.data.error.message)
          })
        }, function(error) {
          $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = false;
          $scope.showEmptyState = true;
          $scope.showDefaultState = false;
          console.log(error.data.error.message)
        })
      }, function (error) {
        $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = false;
        $scope.showEmptyState = true;
        $scope.showDefaultState = false;
        console.log(error)
      });
    }


    // On browser

    else {
      // Get Facebook user data
      FacebookService.getUserData(config.facebookAccessToken).then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.facebookUserData = dataResponse.data;

        // Save Facebook user data
        $cordovaNativeStorage.setItem("facebookUserData", $scope.facebookUserData).then(function () {
        }, function(error) {
          console.error("Unable to cache user data: " + result);
          $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Unable to cache user data',
            duration: 1500
          })
        });
        $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = true;
        $scope.showEmptyState = false;
        $scope.showDefaultState = false;
      }, function(error) {
        $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = false;
        $scope.showEmptyState = true;
        $scope.showDefaultState = false;
        console.log(error.data.error.message)
      })

      // Get Facebook user picture
      FacebookService.getUserPicture(config.facebookUserId).then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.facebookUserPicture = dataResponse.data;
        PhotoService.getBase64FromImageURL($scope.facebookUserPicture.data.url, function(base64_data) {
          $scope.facebookUserPicture.data.base64_data = base64_data;

          // Save Facebook user picture
          $cordovaNativeStorage.setItem("facebookUserPicture", $scope.facebookUserPicture).then(function () {
          }, function(error) {
            console.error("Unable to cache user data: " + result);
            $ionicLoading.show({
              template: 'Unable to cache user data',
              duration: 1500
            })
          });
          $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = true;
          $scope.showEmptyState = false;
          $scope.showDefaultState = false;
        }, function(error) {
          $scope.showFacebookEmptyState = false;
          $scope.showEmptyState = true;
          $scope.showDefaultState = false;
          console.log(error.data.error.message)
        })
      });
    }

    // Determine view state
    $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userPicture").then(function (value) {
        $scope.userPicture = value;
    }, function (error) {
        //$log.log(error);
    });
    $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userProfile").then(function (value) {
      $scope.userProfile = value;
    }, function (error) {
        //$log.log(error);
    });
    $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userSelectedCategories").then(function (value) {
      $scope.userSelectedCategories = value;
    }, function (error) {
        //$log.log(error);
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: you should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/